# Where are the X11 libraries stored?

Tags: macos, x11, xlib

I just started teaching myself XLib, and I'm trying to figure out where everything is located.  I've found the header files to be located at `/opt/X11/include` (I'm using MacOS if that's relevant), but I have no idea where I should tell gcc to look for the actual libraries.  I know they're somewhere in `/opt/X11/lib`, but there are so many subdirectories I don't know where to look.  Specifically, I'm trying to find the library file(s) associated with `X11/Xlib.h`.  Help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

On linux the library is libX11.so (it might be a link e.g. libX11.so -> libX11.so.6.3.0) and it is under the directory /usr/lib64.